# Unreasonable sense of unfairness

Tags: single-word-requests

There may be a few, but I'm trying to remember a specific word for someone having a baseless sense of unfairness, along with the associated anger.

Not entitled or spoiled, but basically the same meaning. It's driving me crazy...

Not a term, but a single word.

Comment: Are you thinking of ***indignant***?

Comment: @Jim YES!!! Thank you Jim!!! I really am as excited as my punctuation indicates.

Comment: If you had said an idiom was acceptable, perhaps : *He has a chip on his shoulder*.

Comment: I'm glad you found your word, but indignant does not necessarily mean an unreasonable sense of unfairness.  "feeling or showing anger because of something that is unfair or wrong : very angry", [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indignant).  One can, for example, be indignant at the truly unfair treatment meted out to someone else, even a stranger.  But again, I am glad you found your word.

Comment: Consider the terms "[victim playing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_playing)" (perhaps more commonly expressed as "playing the victim") and "[victim mentality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_mentality)."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [**haughtiness**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haughtiness) which is in line with that same "this can't be happening to me, do you have any idea who I am?!" personality.

> having or showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people

Comment: Thanks for your response and teaching me a new term, but that's not it. The definition of the word I'm looking for literally means a flawed perception of unfairness.

Comment: ALSO, I just remembered, the term also refers to the attitude or anger associated with the flawed perception of unfairness. As in a kid thinking it's unfair that they can't stay up with the adults. Or the new mailroom guy feeling like they should've got a bigger bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Covet-   involves a sense of unfairness...so and so has something and doesn't deserve it, but I do...he wants it and he wants the other person to be without it..Also wanting something we don't have and resenting bitterly the person or people that have it...
One of the Old Testaments 10 commandments
Thou shalt not covet